# Is there a shortcut to popup the completer in texstudio?

Tags: texstudio

Texstudio has a handy feature that is popup a list of known labels or bibids when you \cite or \ref. For example:

[image]

However, I found this tooltip is not that stable. Many times, it disappears when I am still typing for unknown reason or if you unfortunately click the mouse. like this
[image]

The annoying thing is that if the tooltip disappears, it never popup again automatically. I found I have to delete `\cite` and retype start from `\` to make tooltip appear again.

So I am wondering if there is a shortcut to popup the tooltip again after it disappear?

Comment: As far as I know there's no shortcut, you have to do exactly as you've done so far. Delete all `\cite` cmd and retype it. If it bugs you that much [Report as a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press `Ctrl+Space` to reopen the completer.

Comment: Hi, Tim Hoffmann. Are you sure about this? It is not working for me

Comment: Yes. To check, if it's working, you can also run it from the menu `Idefix -> Complete -> Normal`

Comment: Thank you. I understand why. My input has taken over ctrl+space